# JAVA - extends vs interface - Strategy design pattern

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, code-reuse

I have a scenario where multiple concrete classes `extends` multiple `Abstract` classes. I am at a loss to come up with a clean structure, reduce the number of files and avoid code repetition.

The ask is to display various sensor values in different ways based on some criteria. Sensor values like temperature, voltage, current etc can have an anlaog widget, a numeric label or a combination of both. I have 3 `Abstract` classes for the 3 different kind of views. These 3 `Abstract` classes implement a method that defines how the view is to be drawn. Each sensor view `extends` the 3 `Abstract` classes and implements methods to read the sensor, perform some engineering conversion and display the sensor value.
The problem here is that the code implemented by the concrete classes is the same no matter what `Abstract` class it extends. `CAnalogTempView`, `CDigitalTempView` and `CCustomTempView` all have the same implementation but extend different classes.

This seems awkward. The code is repeated and the number of source files increases by a factor of 3. Am I missing something simple here? Is there a pattern for a problem like this? Can I `extends` the sensor view classes at run time? The actual code is more complicated. I have over simplified the problem statement for clarity.

EDIT:
There are several sensor views which implement the `Abstract` view classes. The `calculate()` method for each sensor is different. I have just listed 3 concrete classes for simplicity. In the same vein, you would have `CAnalogVoltageView`, `CDigitalVoltageView`, `CCustomVoltageView` and `CAnalogCurrentView`, `CDigitalCurrentView`, `CCustomCurrentView` and so on

```
public abstract class CView
{
    public abstract void draw();
    public abstract void calculate();
}

public abstract class CAnalogView extends CView
{
    public void draw()
    {
         // draw specific to analog view
    }
}

public abstract class CDigitalView extends CView
{
    public void draw()
    {
        // draw specific to digital view
    }
}

public abstract class CCustomView extends CView
{
    public void draw()
    {
        // draw specific to custom view
    }
}

// concrete implementations
public class CAnalogTempView extends CAnalogView
{
    public void calculate()
    {
        // read and calculate sensor value here
    }
}

public class CDigitalTempView extends CDigitalView
{
    public void calculate()
    {
        // calculate here. same as CAnalogTempView::calculate()
    }
}

public class CCustomTempView extends CCustomView
{
    public void calculate()
    {
        // calculate here. same as CAnalogTempView::calculate()
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably overworking inheritance. It's easily done. Have a think about using delegation.

Comment: What you need to do when thinking about abstraction like this is consider "What does each function need to be able to run it's individual needs". That is to say, if you can do all the work for getting a few values which `calculate()` can then operate upon, you should just get those values and pass them.

Comment: Are there more classes that extend CAnalogView besides CAnalogTempView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Strategy design pattern** will help you. Well One thing that you should kept in mind.

> Use as **less** `extends` keyword as possible, better to use **Interfaces** or **composition**.

**Solution:**

Encapsulate the `calculate()` because `calculate()` may change in future and it has different implementations.

**Process:**

1) Make an interface `CalcInterface` that has `calculate()`.

2) Implement `CalcInterface` by 3 different classes say `CAnalogTempCalc`, `CDigitalTempCalc` and `CCustomTempCalc`. Then implement `calculate()` in each class.

3) Now its time for `composition`. Say you have `Sensor` class (main class) ... then make the object of type `CalcInterface`. PS: it will has `display()` that is common for all.

4) And now make 3 different classes that `extends Sensor` say `AnalogSensor`, `TempSensor` and `CustomSensor` ...

5) Now at runtime you will make any of type's ( `CAnalogTempCalc`, `CDigitalTempCalc` and `CCustomTempCalc` ) object.

**EDIT :**

Following is the Class Diagram, I am not good with art ... but this diagram will give you some idea about classes and interfaces and how to use them efficiently.

[image]

Now you will be able to implement as many *CustomCalcuations* as you want by just implementing the `CalcInterface` ...

This is the ***POWER*** to accommodate change without changing current implementation you have by following Strategy design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the `Sensor` implementation from the `View`. The sensor doesn't need to know that a view exists. I would create a `Sensor` interface with a method `calculate()` that returns some result (I used `double` in the example):

```
public interface Sensor {
    double calculate();
}

public class TemperatureSensor implements Sensor {
    public double calculate() {
        // specific implementation for the temperature sensor
    }
}
```

And change the abstract `CView` to have an attribute for the sensor, and an implementation of `calculate()` that simply displays the result calculated by the specific sensor.

```
public abstract class CView {
    private Sensor sensor;

    CView(Sensor sensor) {
        this.sensor = sensor;
    }

    public abstract void draw();

    public void calculate() {
        double result = this.sensor.calculate();
        // display the result
    }
}

public class CDigitalView extends CView {
    CDigitalView(Sensor sensor) {
        super(sensor);
    }

    public void draw() {
        // draw specific to digital view
    }
}
```

So every time you create a view, you pass the sensor you want to display in the constructor like this:

```
Sensor temperatureSensor = new TemperatureSensor();
CView digitalView = new CDigitalView(temperatureSensor);
```

This way, you would have a concrete class for each sensor and a concrete class for each view. If *n* is the number of views and *m* is the number of sensors, your total is *n* + *m*. With analog, digital, and custom views, plus temperature, voltage, and current sensors, you would get 6 classes.

In contrast, by creating a concrete class for each sensor for each view, as you were doing, you would get *n* * *m* concrete classes. In the example above, the total would be 9, not counting the 3 abstract view classes.

Comment: The calculate() method for each sensor is different. For the same sensor, the calculate() method would be the same for all kinds of views.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which I can see is you can provide the implementation for `public abstract void calculate()` in your `CView` class. If any class wants to override it ll override it